# SSMS 17.9.1 crashes on "connect"

Tags: ssms-2017

I installed SSMS 17.9.1.

When I start SSMS it crashes when I try to connect to the database server.

See this 5 second video
https://vimeo.com/302442420/2ed86b92d8

My only action is to click on the "connect" button.
Then the object explorer appears quickly followed by SSMS shutdown.

How can I get SSMS to work properly ?

Comment: Please check ssms logs. Have a look at this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/viewing-the-sql-server-error-log?view=sql-server-2017 for log location.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on the Microsoft Developer Network.

**This is the solution that worked:**

1. Uninstall SSMS
2. Uninstall Visual Studio 2015 IsoShell
3. Uninstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2015(or 2017 if you are using it) Redistributable. Uninstall both x86 and x64 if they're on your computer.
4. Reinstall Visual Studio 2015 IsoShell
5. Reinstall SSMS
6. Reinstall Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable

It took a long time!

See [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/baaace41-1286-4303-b31f-0ac935452e95/why-is-ssms-1791-crashing?forum=sqltools#682e80a7-08cf-4ca0-a74e-ce0137c06eba).